# handle unterminated string constant in javascript

Tags: java, javascript, sql-server, jsp

When my sql server SP returning string with new line character and in my jsp I pass it to script function and display it in alert box it throws :

```
function sample(notes){
    alert(notes);
}

Error:
script1015: unterminated string constant
```

I can handle it in SP like

```
REPLACE(BDT.Notes , CHAR(13) + CHAR(10), ''<br/>'' ) as Notes
```

But is there any way to handle it in script?

Comment: You can't handle malformed language constructs within a language as it not valid language in that language.  Fix up the strings in the jsp before you output them?

Comment: @AlexK. Can you give sample code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try below

```
 someText = someText.replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm,"");
```

see link http://www.textfixer.com/tutorials/javascript-line-breaks.php

Comment: Not working I am getting three errors : 1) SCRIPT1015: Unterminated string constant  2) SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'  3) SCRIPT257: Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101.

Comment: This was exactly the fix that I needed (well, I was using a Java scriptlet and I needed to escape it before it got to the javascript at all, but similar method in java exists. `string.replaceAll("\r|\n|\r\n","");`). Thanks!